# PHP identical arrays return false on check

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I am checking whether two arrays are identical and even though I know they are, my conditional returns false.

Here are the two arrays: http://pastebin.com/knekiW67

Here is the code:

```
$stored_items = (Array1 in Pastebin link)
$new_items = (Array2 in Pastebin link)

if($stored_items === $new_items) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I've even checked the two arrays using https://www.diffchecker.com/ and it responds that they are identical.

Does anyone know why it's returning false?

Comment: I actually ended up using serialize() on the two arrays before comparing them which worked.

Answer (score 0):

`===` if not working for array(only string and int)

for checking array need use http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-ukey.php with special callback

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: Hey, `===` operator not working for array

Comment: His arrays are nested several levels deep. `array_diff` doesn't recurse.

Comment: Please link to English documentation, not Russian.